# using MyProj; at the user class definition or MyProj.MyClass at the specific method(s)?

Tags: c#, reference

Ok, let me explain:

Whenever you start a class in .Net and let's say you have another project you've developed referenced which has non static class(es) you need to use...

You have 2 options (That I know of)

Place a using at the top of your class meaning you won't need to explicitly name the whole project each time you need it's classes

```
using FooBarProj;

public FooBar MyMethod()
{
     FooBar fb = new FooBar();
     //Do stuff
     return fb;
}
```

Or do explicitly implement those:

```
public FooBarProj.FooBar MyMethod()
{
     FooBarProj.FooBar fb = new FooBarProj.FooBar();
     //Do stuff
     return fb;
}
```

Does this make an effective difference at all? either efficiency at execution, compiling, whatever? or its simply a dev convenience issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference after compiling the code.

Either using an `using` statement, or using the whole class namespace and name, is the same thing after all.

When compiling to CIL code, references to types are a single thing, each reference contains all the information, regardless of how you coded that reference.

**Referencing a class with a different name**

You can even rename a class if you whant, doing this:

```
using TheString = System.String;
```

Now you can refer to `System.String` using the name `TheString` in your code.

**All of these produces the same compiled code**

- `string`
- `System.String`
- `String` (if you place `using System;` at the beginning)
- `TheString` (if you place `using TheString = System.String;` at the beginning)

**Conclusion: All `using` statements are just convenience.**

Comment: On an interface you have both options when its requested to implement it (implicit or explicit), is it the same thing than here? convenience?

Comment: That is something different. An explicit impleneted interface won't be callable by the usual way. When you want to call an explicit implemented interface of an object, you first have to cast it to the Interface.

Comment: In that case it is not. Implicit implementation will require that a method is public... explicit implementation does not expose the method publicly through the class, only through the interface.

Comment: When using implicit implementation, access through the public method will be faster than through the interface, even if the public method is made virtual.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a dev convenience issue. The first version is better in all circumstances other than there is a similar class name in different namespaces. The explicit namespace declaration before the class is needed when there are same class names in different namespaces like. Dog23.class1 and dog45.class1. Always the first version if it works. It is shorter and readable.